# Unable to update data in Android Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm developing one app where I am storing the data. The operations, insert,Update and select they are all working fine except update. 
While I am updating the database, my app is crashing and it's giving the following error:
No such Columns existed.
I checked many times but I am unable to find the issue. 
Below I'm sharing my code which I have written so far.

**Register.java**

```
/**
 * Created by yadapras on 7/8/2016.
 */
public class Register  {

    String phone_no;
    String uname,password,re_password,name,email,imei_no,dev_model;
    int os_version;

    public void setUname(String uname)
    {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getUname()
    {
        return this.uname;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return this.password;
    }
    public void setRe_password(String re_password)
    {
        this.re_password = re_password;
    }
    public String getRe_password()
    {
        return this.re_password;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEmail()
    {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setPhone_no(String phone_no)
    {
        this.phone_no = phone_no;
    }
    public String getPhone_no()
    {
        return this.phone_no;
    }
    public void setImei_no(String imei_no)
    {
        this.imei_no = imei_no;
    }
    public String getImei_no()
    {
        return this.imei_no;
    }

    public void setDev_model(String dev_model)
    {
        this.dev_model=dev_model;
    }
    public String getDev_model()
    {
        return this.dev_model;
    }

    public void setOs_version(int os_version)
    {
        this.os_version = os_version;
    }
    public int getOs_version()
    {
        return this.os_version;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
   package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by yadapras on 6/26/2016.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText a,b;
    String usr,pass;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.BLogin)
        {
            a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
            usr = a.getText().toString();
            b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
            pass = b.getText().toString();



            String password = null;

            if( a.getText().toString().length() == 0 || usr == "" || usr == null)
                a.setError( " User name is required!" );
            if( b.getText().toString().length() == 0 || pass =="" || pass == null)
                b.setError( "Password is required!" );
            else{
                password = helper.searchPass(usr);
            }

            if (pass.equals(password) && password != null)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmpDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("usr",usr);

                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String uid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER; // Not used in current scenario
                String model = Build.MODEL;
                int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                String versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE; // not used in current scenario
                String msg = "IMEI No: "+uid+"\n"+"Manufacturer is :"+manufacturer+"\n"+"Model is :"+model+"\n"+"Os Version is :"+version+"\n"+"VersionRelease is :"+versionRelease;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                Register r = new Register();
                r.setImei_no(uid);
                r.setDev_model(model);
                r.setOs_version(version);
                r.setUname(usr);

                helper.updateTable(r); /*For updating table with new Coloumn*/

                startActivity(intent);


            }
            else
            {
                Toast err_pass = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UserName and Password don't Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                err_pass.show();
            }

        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.BSignup)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registration.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.ArrayMap;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by yadapras on 7/8/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "registrationDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "registrations";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD= "password";
    public static final String COLUMN_RE_PASSWORD= "re_password";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME= "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL= "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE_NO= "phone_no";

    /*Adding three coloumn IMEI_NO,OS_Version,Model_Device Respectively*/

    public static final String COLUMN_IMEI_NO = "imei_no";
    public static final String COLUMN_DEV_MODEL = "dev_model";
    public static final String COLUMN_OS_VERSION = "os_version";


    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table registrations(id integer primary key not null, " +
            "username text not null, password text not null, re_password text not null, name text not null, email text not null," +
            "phone_no number not null,imei_no text, dev_model text, os_version text);";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.sqLiteDatabase=sqLiteDatabase;
        Log.d("#####Table Value",TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME ;
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void registerUser(Register r) {
        /*Inserting anything in to the dataBase make sure it should be writable*/
        sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "select * from registrations";
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();

        Log.d("##count",""+count);
        values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
        Log.d("##id",r.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,r.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,r.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_RE_PASSWORD,r.getRe_password());
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,r.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, r.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONE_NO, r.getPhone_no());

        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,values); /*this will insert Register object in to the Database*/

        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String usr) {
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "select username,password from "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
         String a,b ; // a and b will be userName and Password respectively
        b = "Not Found";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);
                Log.d("##username from db",a);
                if (a.equals(usr))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }

    public JSONObject showDetail(String usr) {
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query ="SELECT * FROM  registrations   where username='"+usr+"'" ;//"select * from registrations where username = p";
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {

                int columnsQty = cursor.getColumnCount();
                for (int idx=0; idx<columnsQty; ++idx) {
                    try {
                        data.put(cursor.getColumnName(idx),cursor.getString(idx));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("###Data Value",data.toString());
        return data;

    }

    public void updateTable(Register r) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_IMEI_NO,r.getImei_no());
        Log.d("###Column_IMEI_NO",r.getImei_no());
        cv.put(COLUMN_DEV_MODEL,r.getDev_model());
        cv.put(COLUMN_OS_VERSION,r.getOs_version());
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"username = "+r.getUname(),null);

    }
}
```

// LOG Generate :-

```
07-19 18:21:20.246 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp D/##username from db: h
07-19 18:21:20.256 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp D/###Column_IMEI_NO: 356619054923013
07-19 18:21:20.257 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: h
07-19 18:21:20.259 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-19 18:21:20.260 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp, PID: 15581
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: h (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE registrations SET imei_no=?,os_version=?,dev_model=? WHERE username = h
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1574)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1522)
                                                                                     at com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp.DatabaseHelper.updateTable(DatabaseHelper.java:146)
                                                                                     at com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:72)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
07-19 18:25:45.117 15581-15591/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.528ms
07-19 18:26:20.304 15581-15581/com.example.yadapras.mobiltyemp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15581 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If you may post the logcat?

Comment: why downVoted can anyone tell me reason ???

Comment: I read from the log given, that your app tries to write to a table claiming a column h which the database assumes to be not present.

Comment: @Delettant it is present , i'm updating column where user_ value is h which is  already exist in db.. i was doing mistake in writing update query now i Correct that , and its working fine now

Comment: @Nidhin Ans help me .. plzz mark as a correct answer

Comment: please mark as a ques which helps to others thank u

Comment: will anyone tell me why its downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the syntax of your update query,

Your version:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"username = "+r.getUname(),null);
```

Update it like this .

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,"username = ?",new String[]{r.getUname()});
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: it's Working Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
public void updateTable(Register r) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COLUMN_IMEI_NO,r.getImei_no());
    Log.d("###Column_IMEI_NO",r.getImei_no());
    cv.put(COLUMN_DEV_MODEL,r.getDev_model());
    cv.put(COLUMN_OS_VERSION,r.getOs_version());
    String updateQuery = "Update registrations set " + COLUMN_IMEI_NO + " = '"+ r.getImei_no() +"' where " + COLUMN_USERNAME + "="+"'"+ r.getUname() +"'";
    database.execSQL(updateQuery);
    database.close();

}
```

Comment: can u tell me y my question is down voted.. what i make wrong if i will get ans , from next time i will keep in my mind and ask here

Answer (score 1):

// code to update the single contact  .Contact is the getter setter on which you have set your data

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());  
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());  

    // updating row  
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try Like This (this works for me)


          public boolean rowIdExists(String StrId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from " + TABLE_Name
            + " where id=?", new String[]{StrId});
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    /*cursor.close();
    db.close();*/
    return exists;
}

public void insertuserrate(String Str[], Context cxt) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*
    Cursor c = null;
*/
    String strId = "";
    //ArrayList<String> userRatepoit= new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        {
            values.put(KEY_RID, Str[0]);
            values.put(ALL_name, Str[1]);
            values.put(ALL_isbn, Str[2]);
            values.put(ALL_catid, Str[3]);

            if (rowIdExists(Str[0])) {
                db.update(TABLE_Name, values, "id " + "=" + Str[0], null);
                Log.d("update success", TABLE_Name);
            } else {
                db.insert(TABLE_Name, null, values);
                Log.d("inserted success", TABLE_Name);
            }
            // Closing database connection
        }
        try {
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```